# How do I find/access account public_html directories from my root access on my dedicated server - WHM cpanel

Tags: apache, webserver, putty, whm

I have dedicated server and have root accesss via ssh putty  - I have 1 account set up on the server but I'm trying to workout how i can access the public_html directory of this account from  root@ds-44498 [~]#  the public_html in the root is empty.

I'm trying to copy a file from the root to the account public_html folder

I have WHM - cpanel

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Have found answer: in /home/accountname/public_html/

thanks